# How to get id in itemclick and move to next activity in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to get id from Listview. I have used arrayadapter and using itemclick. I want to click on particular list item and move to next activity so that I can access subfolders into it. I am using (ksoap) .net web services.

```
 SoapObject dataresponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                Log.i("myData", dataresponse.toString());

                datalist = new String[dataresponse.getPropertyCount()];
                for(int i=0; i< dataresponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)

                datalist[i] = dataresponse.getProperty(i).toString();

                treedata = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.treedata);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datalist);

                treedata.setAdapter(adapter);

                treedata.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// After clicking on list item I have subfolders into it, how can i get those subfolders.

                    //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Files_Folders_Activity.class);

                    //  int item_Id = (Integer) treedata.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                    //  intent.putExtra("item_Id", item_Id);

                    //  startActivity(intent);  
                    }
                });
```

Next Activity:

```
   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.files_folders_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    subfolderTreedata();

}

public void subfolderTreedata(){
    try {

 SoapObject subfolderrequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SUBFOLDERTREEDATA_METHOD);

 subfolderrequest.addProperty("FolderID", FolderID);
 subfolderrequest.addProperty("UserID", UserID);

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 envelope.dotNet = true;
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(subfolderrequest);

 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
 androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_SUBFOLDERTREEDATA , envelope);

 SoapObject dataresponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

 Log.i("subfoldersData", dataresponse.toString());

 subfolderslist = new String[dataresponse.getPropertyCount()];
 for(int i=0;i< dataresponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)

 subfolderslist[i] = dataresponse.getProperty(i).toString();

 subfolderstreedata = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subfolderstreedata);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subfolderslist);

 subfolderstreedata.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
```

Web Services:

```
  POST /InterLogicsMobile/InterLogics.asmx HTTP/1.1
  Host: 192.168.1.5
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: length
  SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/TreeDataSubFolder"

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<TreeDataSubFolder xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <FolderID>string</FolderID>
    <UserId>string</UserId>
  </TreeDataSubFolder>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TreeDataSubFolderResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <TreeDataSubFolderResult>
        <FileFolderDetails>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Name>string</Name>
          <SubjectType>string</SubjectType>
        </FileFolderDetails>
        <FileFolderDetails>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Name>string</Name>
          <SubjectType>string</SubjectType>
        </FileFolderDetails>
      </TreeDataSubFolderResult>
    </TreeDataSubFolderResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please suggest how to get subfolder after clicking on itemclick listener. I am trying to get the answer from last 4 days.

I am not able to get subfolder into my next activity, I have to pass FolderId and UserId both into soapobject pas parameter.

Comment: you want a item from clicked listitem

Comment: Yes, But I am using web services, I don't know what to do. So Please suggest? I can give more information.

Comment: can you see the items on listview?

Comment: Yes, I can see the item in list view?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this : 
i hope this will be help to you..if you need you use this..

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            String des = o.toString();              
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), Next_Activity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", des);
                startActivity(myIntent);

    }
    });
```

This for get the intent values previous activity:

```
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id_backup= b.getString("id");
```

Comment: I amtrying please give me some time.

Comment: How to get the mIntent in next Activity?

Comment: i have edit my post see that i gave the intent details for put and get values from intent.if you any queries ask me. i hope this will help you.

Comment: @ Tamilarasi Sivaraj yes it is giving me Id of that particular item but, I am not able to show my subfolder into it. I have edited my question please check

Comment: will you need this subfolderslist values from clicked listitem?

Comment: yes, I have web services created, in which I am having folders and files.

Comment: where you have specify the files and folder you used only list for getting web service response?

Comment: @ Tamilarasi Sivaraj Are these will not be on server? I have placed files and folders using listview in array adapter only. I mean I am getting these files from server.

Comment: \can you post your listview result here?

Comment: anyType{TreeData=anyType{ID=13002; FolderName=My Drive; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; TreeData=anyType{ID=13006; FolderName=Testing1; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; TreeData=anyType{ID=13007; FolderName=Testing123; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; }

Comment: i think if you click the first item you get your folder name my drive right

Comment: Yes, right I am getting folder name (anyType{ID=13002; FolderName=My Drive; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }), But I need to get subfolders from it.

Comment: but your ws response not print the subfloders

Comment: Yes, Right,Also, Is there any need to pass this id to Folder_ID(please see web services), so that i can get Folder_Id Dynamically? like subfolderrequest.addProperty("FolderID", item_Id);

Comment: can you post your emulator design for listview

Comment: can you see the image? I need 15 reputation to postimage.

Comment: yes i have seen it but the folder name is only there but subfolder name is not there how can you get it..

Comment: using web services, I need to pass Folder_ID to soapobject and need to get next list of folders and files those are placed into it.

Comment: i think you use it that will be seperate the responses      SoapObject simpleSuggestion = (SoapObject) nameResult.getProperty(i);   id = simpleSuggestion.getProperty("id")
          .toString();

Comment: where do you want me to put this code, in subfolder web services activity?

Comment: in side the for loop because you put all webservice in one list without separate. so you first separate your response like folder name sub folder and ids for use this code

Comment: nameResult.getProperty(i); id = simpleSuggestion.getProperty("id") .toString(); you put you response objects name inside getproperty

Comment: SoapObject subfolderrequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SUBFOLDERTREEDATA_METHOD);
     
     subfolderrequest.addProperty("FolderID", item_Id);
     subfolderrequest.addProperty("UserID", UserID);

I am trying to do this, Have you used web services ever?

Comment: have you got the subfloder name from ws

Comment: In Log I am getting any type{}, Not wsdl, Yes I have wsdl, I am using .net web services

Comment: yes you wsdl file is help to consume your ws from android that would got all request and response detail can you see that?

Comment: yes, I can see that. I have two String (Folder_ID and user_ID) I need to pass Folder_ID that we have generated through on item_click (I think). But when I am switched to next activity it is not showing subfolders. I have used same listview and adapter as I have used in after login activity.

Comment: HI, catch you later, Please give me some time.

Comment: ok subfloder name is not came from your webservice so how to show the next activity....?

Comment: through Intent I think, I can get Listview item_id through which I can get next list of folder and files into that item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pass a parameter to the web service when an item is clicked to get the sub folders? If so is it an index number or parent folder's name?

Comment: I am trying to get list item(folder) where I have subfolders into it. how to use Intent into it?

Comment: You didn't understand my question properly. It'll be easier for me to give you a solution based on the answer you give me to that. :)

Comment: @ JanithaR: when I will click on item it will move on further activity in which I have subfolders. I have web services for subfolders, but I don't understand how to get these from listView item click?